# How to populate a DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I have the following database schema:
[image]

Here's how I populate a DropDownList in my AreaController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Area area = areaRepository.GetArea(id);
    JefeRepository jefe = new JefeRepository();
    ViewData["Jefes"] = new SelectList(jefe.FindAllJefes().ToList(), "ID", "Nombre", area.Jefe.Nombre);
    return View(area);
}
```

Then in my View I display it like so:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("IDJefe", (SelectList)ViewData["Jefes"]) %>
```

The DropDownList loads correctly but only shows the Name of the Jefe. I want to display both name and last name. How can I achieve this?

I've tried doing something like this but it only display the first name.

```
ViewData["Jefes"] = new SelectList(jefe.FindAllJefes().ToList(), "ID", "Nombre", area.Jefe.Nombre + area.Jefe.Apellido);
```

This is how it shows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class you can make an property which will combine it for you and also can be bind to your list, f.e. if I have Person class:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } }
}
```

Then you can easily bind it like:

```
ViewData["Persons"] = new SelectList(persons, "Id", "FullName ", ...);
```

As far as it have just the getter it will not involved into your business logic processes - it will only helps ;)

PS. Sorry for another example, but I really do not understand spanish ;)

Comment: I tried typing in "Nombre" + "Apellido" and it gives me an exception stating that the model doesn't have that property. I'll try your suggestion. :)

Comment: You can only specify one public member that will be bind as display member. Property that combines them both will do the job :) Try my example and tell me if it's resolves your problem...

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY. Great answer! :) I'll write a tutorial for this common question. Thanks again.